# javascript & css: how to dynamically create SVG on a overlay div and define size

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am quite new to html and using css: I have introduced the svg bush&zoom chart my page and want it to be triggered as an overlay div: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I defined the following css:

```
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#hover{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

and defined the following body structure:

```
<body>
<div class="main" id="maindiv">
  <div id="overlay" onclick="off()">
    <svg id="hover" width="960" height="500"></svg>
  </div>
  ...
  [other div]
  ...
</div>
```

I have the function on() to trigger the overlay to be displayed:

```
function on(){
  document.getElementBtId("overlay").style.display = 'block';
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  ...
  [codes to populate the svg]
  ...
}
```

The result turns out to be as the function on() and the overlay div is displayed and the svg is displayed in **total black color**, there should be misconfiguration in the css though the svg is functionable.

I also want to dynamically create and delete the svg on trigger in function on().

Can anyone suggest what to modify in the code to fix the black color issue and dynamic svg creation?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing in you CSS suggests you set any paint for the SVG content, so any grafical element inside will be rendered with the default `fill: black; stroke: none`. What color do you expect, and where do you set it?

Comment: Expects the svg's background color white and stroke blue, same as the demo in above link. But I am not sure where to put and what format to put, in the css #hover{ } or in the svg itself.

Comment: You'll have to identify the elements inside the SVG you want to color. If they do not yet get a class attribute on creation, set an appropriate one so you can distinguish by color. Then, set `fill` and `stroke` properties for these classes in your stylesheet.